# Floating 2 elements with a responsive layout

Tags: css, css-float, responsive-design

I have 2 divs within my footer and I want div 1 positioned to the left side of the screen and div 2 to be positioned to the right side of the screen.

Div 1 has an explicit width of 300px, whereas div 2 only contains a list of elements floated left.

When the page shrinks down I want div 2 to drop underneath div 1. How is the best way to do this? Do I float both left? Do I place div 1 above div 2 in the code? Do I give them both an explicit width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just float the left side div to the left and the right side div to the right, and if the containing div shrinks too much, it should stack them.

HTML -

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="left">Left</div>
<div id="right">Right</div>
</div>​
```

CSS -

```
#parent {
    width: 25px;
}

#left {
    float: left;
}

#right {
    float: right;
}​
```

Check out this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/LaqBm/

Comment: What would you recommend as the best way to ensure the parent spans the height of the elements, as now all its children are floated it has no height.

Comment: Add <div style="clear: both;"></div> inside the parent, below the children.

Answer (score 0):

You need to float both container elements and give them a fixed width.